# Appending innerHTML to a div that is already appended inside a loop

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $('#main-div').html("Goodbye"); // This Works if not commented out
  One();
  /* FUNCTION ONE */
  function One() {
    Two();
  }
  /* FUNCTION TWO */
  function Two() {
    var test = 'TEST';
    var selector = document.querySelectorAll("testing");
    selector.innerHTML = test;
    console.log(selector.innerHTML); // This works
    $('#main-div').append('<div><div class="testing></div></div>'); // This does not work
    alert("Hello There"); // This works
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Hello
<br><br>
<div id="main-div"></div>
```

I am trying to get the javascript countdown to append to a div. The div itself is appended to another div that is outside of the script.

Working inside a loop with dynamic data. I am purposely blocking the interval for now. The console log does reflect expiration for each dynamic item without a problem, but it does not show up on the actual page.

I imagine there is an issue with the innerHTML.

```js
var expiration = data[i]['expiration'];

var expirationDate = [];

expirationDate = new Date(expiration).getTime();

//                  var x = setInterval(function() {

var now = new Date().getTime();

var distance = [];

distance = expirationDate - now;

days = [];
hours = [];
mintues = [];
seconds = [];

var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

countdown = [];

countdown = days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds";

var displayCountdown = document.getElementsByClassName("expiration-countdown");

displayCountdown.innerHTML = countdown;

console.log(displayCountdown.innerHTML); // I can see all the data here no problem

if (distance < 0) {
  //clearInterval(x);
  // displayCountdown.innerHTML = "This Promotion Has Expired";
}

//                    }, 1000);

if (email == "") {

  if (promoType == "Banner") {
    $('#load-container-expiring').append('<div class="row-center-center padding-top-5 padding-bottom-2"><div>' + promoNameExpiringButton + '</div></div>');
    $('#load-container-expiring').append('<div><div class="wrap-content"><img class="mobile-banner-scale" id="visitor-banner-click" src=' + theBanner + '></div></div>');
    $('#load-container-expiring').append('<div class="padding-top-2"><div class="expiration-countdown"></div></div>'); // nothing is loading here
  }
```

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Comment: Have you tried element.push() to add the results of the math into the arrays?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: You should try this. `document.querySelector(".expiration-countdown");`

Comment: @JesperMartinez Please see my answer

Comment: I made a snippet that mimic the basic set up. You can see that the append does not work, while the console log does.

Comment: @MikeM. Many issues. See my second answer

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByTagName is a collection

```
displayCountdown = document.getElementsByClassName("expiration-countdown")[0];
```

would work but I prefer to use

```
displayCountdown = document.querySelector(".expiration-countdown")
```

and seems to work as expected:

NOTE: I remove a lot of unnecessary array declarations.

```js
const plur = num => num === 1 ? "" : "s";
const expiration = new Date() // data[i]['expiration'];
const expirationDate = new Date(expiration.getTime() + 100000).getTime(); // debug time
let x = setInterval(function() {
  const now     = new Date().getTime();
  const diff    = expirationDate - now;

  const days    = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours   = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));  
  const minutes = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  //const countdown  = `${days} day${plur(days)} ${hours} hour${plur(hours)} ${minutes} minute${plur(minutes)} ${seconds} second${plur(seconds)}`;
  const countdown  = days+' day' + plur(days) +
    hours + ' hour'+ plur(hours) +
    minutes + ' minute' + plur(minutes) +
    seconds + ' second' + plur(seconds);

  document.querySelector(".expiration-countdown").innerHTML = countdown;

  if (diff <= 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    displayCountdown.innerHTML = "This Promotion Has Expired";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="expiration-countdown"></div>
```

Comment: As you can see the code works. So there is something else going on. EITHER you do not have `class="expiration-countdown"` OR perhaps you have `id="expiration-countdown"` ?

Comment: What does `inside/outside the script loop` mean? Is the element added dynamically by some code?

Comment: Do you use my code exactly as it is written or do you try to modify something with the line `document.querySelector(".expiration-countdown").innerHTML = countdown`

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. It works outside the script and any random div i make for it. But it does not work inside. Here is the error.

Comment: VM2658:100 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at loadDataExpiring (<anonymous>:100:98)
    at <anonymous>:47:25

Comment: I'm testing it in Chrome. Just tried in Firefox. Same result. I have no problem seeing it in the console log using documentGetElementsByClassname. Every other version i get the innerHTML Error. I can use your version outside the script. But not inside it.

Comment: I do still not understand what you mean outside and inside “the script” are you using some kind of framework or plugin or use script?

Comment: I made a snippet that mimic the basic set up. You can see that the append does not work, while the console log does.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a HTML collection.

Either use `id` in your html and get element by `getElementById`.

Or

Do

```
var displayCountdown = document.getElementsByClassName("expiration-countdown")[0];
```

So that it will add html to 0th element of class `expiration-countdown`.

```js
(function() {
  var displayCountdown = document.getElementsByClassName("expiration-countdown")[0];
  displayCountdown.innerHTML = 'abc';
})();
```

```html
<div class="expiration-countdown">pqr</div>
```

**Update**

Your snippet is not working because `div` with class `testing` is not present in DOM. See below snippet, I have appendend `div` with class `testing` and its working fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $('#main-div').html("Goodbye"); // This Works if not commented out
  One();
  /* FUNCTION ONE */
  function One() {
    Two();
  }
  /* FUNCTION TWO */
  function Two() {
    var test = 'TEST';
    $('#main-div').append('<div class="testing"></div>');
    var selector = document.querySelector(".testing");
    selector.innerHTML = test;
    console.log(selector.innerHTML); // This works
    alert("Hello There"); // This works
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Hello
<br><br>
<div id="main-div"></div>
```

Comment: @MikeM. I have added snippet, in which it is working fine

Comment: @MikeM. Make sure typed correct classname in your HTML and JS

Comment: I appreciate it very much. I too can get this to work no problem outside of the script loop. It doesn't work inside the script. Only outside of it.

Comment: I made a snippet that mimic the basic set up. You can see that the append does not work, while the console log does.

Comment: I see that for the snippet. Thanks. Can you look closer at my full code and see what's going on? I can see the values in the console log. But not in the div. I could chat with you if needed.

Comment: Did you try with `document.querySelector(".expiration-countdown")` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("expiration-countdown")` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215313/discussion-between-kenny-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 0):

Answering on the NEW code added to the top of the question

There are several issues in that code.

1. `var selector = document.querySelectorAll("testing");` is getting a collection, but there IS no `<testing>` tags in your code.
2. You manage to get an object and add an innerHTML property, but it is not real
3. you append EMPTY content with CLASS testing with a typo (missing end quote), and that can be found using `var selector = document.querySelector(".testing");`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $('#main-div').html("Goodbye"); // This Works if not commented out
  One();
  /* FUNCTION ONE */
  function One() {
    Two();
  }
  /* FUNCTION TWO */
  function Two() {
    var test = 'TEST';
    var selector = document.querySelectorAll("testing"); // it returns an object, not a useful object though
    console.log(selector.length,selector.tagName,selector.textContent); 
    selector.innerHTML = test; // setting a property of a useless object
    console.log("selector innerHTML: ",selector.innerHTML); // This is console.logging a fake property
    $('#main-div').append('<div><div class="testing">TEST</div></div>'); // This works just fine
    selector = document.querySelector(".testing"); // it returns the div now
    console.log(selector.tagName,selector.textContent); 

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Hello
<br><br>
<div id="main-div"></div>
```